# Complex Derivative of $f(z)=z^2\overline{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a quick question in the middle of a problem here. I'm trying to show that $f(z)=z^2\overline{z}$, where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate, is differentiable at $z$ iff $z=0$ by the limit definition.

Should I have
$$\lim_{dz \to 0} \frac{(z+dz)^2\overline{z+dz}-z^2\overline{z}}{dz}?$$

Kindest regards.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your question to bring it closer to the standards of the site. I've changed your notation for complex conjugate to something more standard; I hope that's OK. Please check out the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to find out how to do this for yourself. Also, you can press [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4377495/edit) to play around with the code I've used to format your question, so you can get a feel for how it works.

Comment: I've been assigned to do it both ways. I just haven't used the limit definition in a long time, and wanted to make sure I had it right!

Comment: Hint - $z^2z^*=\vert z \vert^2z$

Comment: Thank you, Theo! I've actually been meaning to learn the coding behind it myself. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnWhite Another handy technique is if you right-click on a mathematical expression, you'll get a special menu: Show Math As $\to$ TeX Commands. This will show you the code for a given expression.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=x(x^2+y^2)+iy(x^2+y^2)=a(x,y)+ib(x,y)$

$a_x=3x^2+y^2. \ a_y=2xy$.

$b_x=2xy. \ b_y=x^2+3y^2$.

$a_x+ib_x=-i(a_y+ib_y)\implies a_x=b_y$ and $b_x=-a_y$ (Cauchy-Riemann)

$f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so it is not analytic.

There are satisfied for a subset of the complex plane, specifically where $x^2=y^2$ and $2xy=-2xy\implies xy=0$. The only solution is when $x=y=0$.